# Laravel 5.2 + How to save record in DB

Tags: php, laravel-5

While working with laravel 5.2 since last 2 weeks, I have found one new method to store records in DB.

For Instance

```
 User table 
 id      name
 1       Test 1
 2       Test 2

 Project Table
 id     user_id      name
 1      1            Project 1
 2      2            Project 2
```

**User** and **Project** table are linked in Foreign Key constraint.

To store in **Project** table, I have used below line of code.

```
Auth::user()->projects()->save($project);
```

Can I have similar kind of solution if I want to store record in **Task** table?
Where project_id and user_id are foreign key constraints of project and user table respectively.

```
Task Table 
id    project_id     user_id      name
1     1              1            test task
```

Comment: Why do you need a 1 to x relationship `user_id` on a task when the project already has a x:1 relationship with a user?

Comment: I am learning Laravel 5.2. I may face such situation while working on real projects.

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple relationships in a table. You just set them up in the same way as if you had one. In your model you just create two functions, one for each relationship.

Comment: @Styphon: Thanks for reply. In case of creating a task(Where task has 2 foreign key references project_id and user_id), how will you write a code to save record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already pivot then You can make it in the following ways:

#### 1 while attaching

```
Auth::user()->projects()->attach([1 => ['name' => $name], 2, 3]);
```

#### 2 while sync

```
Auth::user()->projects()->sync([1 => ['name' => $name], 2, 3]);
```

#### 3 on update pivot

```
Auth::user()->projects()->updateExistingPivot($projectId, ['name' => $name]);
```

#### For read

The pivot data you can access throught a collection of related models - then find a model that interests You and get a `pivot` special field:

```
$project = Auth::user()->projects->find($projectId);
return $project->pivot->name;
```

You can get there but only by the way I show you above.

Comment: Basically I want to know how to create records in DB using Laravel when table has 2 or more foreign keys and not using pivot tables. 

I know the answer if table has only one foreign key.

Comment: You might want to distinguish between the attaching and syncing. Attach adds whereas sync will add and remove and ids not in the sync

Comment: @haakym - I want to know how to add record in table which has 2 or more  foreign key references.

Comment: Well in many-to-many relations in Laravel you create a pivot records on each `attach` or `sync` as @haakym says.

Comment: @FilipKoblański - Thanks for quick reply. -  I am trying to explain the case where task has one-to-one relationship with project as well as user(who has created a task). Will pivot tables come in picture for this scenario? if Yes, how to my pivot table look like because as per my knowledge, pivot tables can connect 2 tables.

Comment: So to update you have the third point of my anserw above. To lookup you need to know the ids and then you can try like: I willl show whit abov in the moment

Comment: You can check it now.

Comment: @FilipKoblański: As per my experience with Laravel, Pivot tables are  mainly used when you want to manage many-to-many relationships. I want to manage 1:x between user and task and 1:x between project and task. Also go through my task table structure.

Comment: So I don't know what's the problem :) You need to create a Task model and create hasMany relation in project and user model - that's all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111135/discussion-between-slayer-and-filip-koblanski).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this. All you have to do is create two functions in your Tasks model, one for each relationship:

```
class Task extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
    public function project()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Project');
    }
}
```

When you save the task you just use attach them as you would with one.

```
$user = User::find(1);
$project = Project::find(1);
$task = Task::create();
$task->user()->attach($user);
$task->project()->attach($project);
$task->save();
```

Comment: Agreed to the answer. so if I need to save project, I write "Auth::user()->projects()->save($project);" code. What should I write to save task in DB?

Comment: I hope I could explain my situation exactly to you now.

Comment: @SLAYER I've updated my answer to include how you attach the user and project to the task.

Comment: Appreciate your inputs mate! Just to clarify myself - Do I need to create 2 different pivot tables "user_task" and "project_task"? Any reference link would help.

Comment: No, there's no pivot table with this. You're doing a one to many relationship, you only need a pivot table for many to many relationships. For example if many users could own the same task, that would then be many to many.

Comment: $task = Task::create(); I think this code may create DB error as we are not passing user_id and project_id at time of creation. Do you think so? Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks for your efforts though.

Comment: It'll only create an error if you make foreign keys in the database, otherwise it will just put 0's in. If you do then you can just do `new Task()` instead and the `save()` will create it.